# calculate standard deviation for ratios

Tags: r, standard-deviation, ratio

I have two groups of intensities I want to compare by calculating the ration and log2 transform to plot as bar plot.
I am wondering how to calculate the standard deviation and how to draw it in the log2 transformed ratios.

Here is some `r` code to have a simple reproducible example. I just summed the two `sd` together, but I guess this is wrong.

```
library("Hmisc") # for the errorbars
int_a <- c(24.6164433981292, 24.3732666667718, 24.2158917104231, 24.4232469941119)
int_b <- c(25.0991272142661, 23.989294370139, 24.4970264975753, 25.7427826868374)
mean_a <- mean(int_a)
mean_b <- mean(int_b)
sd_a <- sd(int_a)
sd_b <- sd(int_b)
ratio <- mean_a/mean_b
barplot(log2(ratio), ylim=c(-1,1))
errbar(x=1, y=log2(ratio), 
       yplus=log2(ratio)+sd_a+sd_b, 
       yminus=log2(ratio)-sd_a-sd_b, 
       add=T, pch=1, cap=.1)
```

Would be nice if somebody could point me to a question like this or give me a solution. I am missing the vocabulary to find the correct solution.

**EDIT**
I tried to incorporate the solution of **StasK** but I am still not sure if the error bars are correct int this way.

```
ratio <- int_a / int_b
mean_ratio <- mean(ratio)
sdmin <- log2(mean_ratio) - sd(ratio)
sdmax <- log2(mean_ratio) + sd(ratio)
barplot(log2(mean_ratio), ylim=c(-1,1))
errbar(x=1, y=log2(mean_ratio), 
       yplus=sdmax, 
       yminus=sdmin, 
       add=T, pch=1, cap=.1)
```

Comment: why don't you want to form `ratio_ab <- int_a / int_b` and analyze that variable as such?

Comment: It is not that I don't want, it is just that I don't know how to do it properly. So if this is the correct way of doing it I would be happy to accept it as an answer and maybe a short reference where I can read how to do it.

Comment: And I am really confused on how to handle the sd in this example to get the proper error bars.

Comment: Why can you not define `a2b <- int_a / int_b`? Error bars are kind of moot for a one-sample test. Worse is that you only have 4 observations. Still, you can calculate a 95% CI with the mean and standard deviation of `a2b`.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" error bars?

Comment: @StasK I am not sure, how to calculate the error bars, since I calculate the `sd` from untransformed `ratio` but I add the error bars to a `log2(mean_ratio)`. So I was wondering if I need to `log2(sd(ratio))` as well and subtract or add this to my `log2(mean_ratio)`.

Comment: Everything must be on the same scale, of course.

Comment: @StasK so `sdmin <- log2(mean(ratio)) - log2(sd(ratio))` would be correct, if I not go for 95% CI?